# What is TypeToken in android?

Tags: android

When do we need to use it ?

```
 final Type serviceErrorType = new TypeToken<ErrorResponseModel<SignUpValidationError>>(){}.getType();
```

What does Type represent here ? Why do we need to add ErrorResponse model and SignUpValidation error?

Answer (score 0):

Java doesn't yet provide a way to represent generic types, so this class does
Check this link.
https://static.javadoc.io/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.6.2/com/google/gson/reflect/TypeToken.html